# How to display woocommerce product sorting option with a custom wp_query or product list on a custom page template (not product archive)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have created a custom page template in WP theme and want to show the products list there with sorting option.

I have implemented `wp_query` to display products but not able to add sorting option for products there.

How can I show sorting option there and filters (woof products filter)?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ORDER BY field_name` in your query

For example
`SELECT * FROM products WHERE type = 'hdd' ORDER BY name`